# Changing Object2 when Object1 is clicked on an Interactive Report in FastReport4

Tags: fastreport

Using and interactive report while being previewed with FastReports 4, I wish to act on an checkbox object other than the one being clicked and have that change show on the preview.

`//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                          
procedure CheckBox1OnPreviewClick(Sender: TfrxView; 
                                  Button: TMouseButton; 
                                   Shift: Integer; 
                            var Modified: Boolean);
begin
TfrxCheckBoxView( Sender ).Checked := NOT TfrxCheckBoxView( Sender ).Checked ;      
Modified := True ;
IF TfrxCheckBoxView( Sender ).Checked Then CheckBox2.Checked := False ;

end;`

With this code, the state of CheckBox1 does change immediately on the preview.  Not so checkbox2.

Any ideas how to change checkbox2 when checkbox1 is clicked on a FastRepor4 interactive report?

Answer (score 0):

Set Memo2.Tag = 2.
Use in the Delphi's code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     frxReport1.AddFunction('function ChangeMemoWithTag(Tag, NewValue: string)');
     frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;

function TForm1.frxReport1UserFunction(const MethodName: String;
  var Params: Variant): Variant;
var i, j: integer;
    c: TObject;
    page: TfrxReportPage;
    modified: Boolean;
begin
     if MethodName = 'CHANGEMEMOWITHTAG' then
       begin
         for i := 0 to frxReport1.PreviewPages.Count-1 do
           begin
             modified := False;
             page := frxReport1.PreviewPages.Page[i];
             for j := 0 to page.AllObjects.Count - 1 do
               begin
                 c := page.AllObjects.Items[j];
                 if c is TfrxMemoView then
                   if TfrxMemoView(c).TagStr = Params[0] then
                     begin
                       TfrxMemoView(c).Text := Params[1];
                       Modified := True;
                     end;
                 if c is TfrxBarCodeView then
                   if TfrxBarCodeView(c).TagStr = Params[0] then
                     begin
                       TfrxBarCodeView(c).Text := Params[1];
                       Modified := True;
                     end;
               end;
             if Modified then
               begin
                 frxReport1.PreviewPages.ModifyPage(i, page);
                 frxReport1.Preview.Refresh;{Repaint for FMX}
               end;  
           end;  
       end;
end;

end.
```

in the report script

```
procedure Memo1OnPreviewClick(Sender: TfrxView; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: Integer; var Modified: Boolean);
var
  s: String;
begin
     s := TfrxMemoView(Sender).Text;
     SetLength(s, Length(s) - 2); // cut off #13#10
     TfrxMemoView(Sender).Text := InputBox('Edit', 'Edit Memo2 text:', s);
     Modified := True;       
     ChangeMemoWithTag('2', TfrxMemoView(Sender).Text);
end;
```